# Which is correct, “someone named something” or “someone called something”?

Tags: word-choice

It seems to me that there has been a move away from designating people by saying “named” when identifying someone as opposed to saying “called,” for example - in a news report.

Saying “named” seems more precise  - I would use “called” with a nickname - i.e.  A man called Rocky or  Butch.

Comment: I think you'll need to be more specific about what your question is - at the moment you've typed two statements, neither of which is a question.

Comment: I tried to fix this question.

Answer (score 1):

Saying someone us called by a name C allows one to provide either the given name, or a nickname (like “Rocky,” “Butch,” or “The Mooch”), whereas saying someone is named with a name N would normally mean it is their legal name.